# Call function with parameter JSP

Tags: java, jsp, el

EDIT : swapp'd `${h.helloWorldName('Audren')}` with `${h.getHelloWorldName('Audren')}`

I have a test class :

```
public class classtest {

    private String helloWorld;
    private String helloWorldName;

    public String getHelloWorld(){
        return "Hello world!";
    }

    public void setHelloWorld(String s) {
        helloWorld = s;
    }

    public String getHelloWorldName(String s) {
        return getHelloWorld() + s;
    }
```

In my jsp i want to print the result of my method getHelloWorldName. Here is what i tried so far :

```
<jsp:useBean id="h" class="com.test.classtest" scope="page" />
<c:out value="${h.helloWorldName('Audren'}" />
```

But with no success. Am i missing something ? I also tried `#{h.helloWorldName('Audren'}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're just missing a parenthesis (and also remove the ''). 
Correct syntax:

```
"${h.helloWorldName(Audren)}"
```